# why does parentNode replace all elements of td and not the ones specified?

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute, parent-node

**Hi!**

Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong? (No I do not have access to edit the HTML.)

Im trying to put **id="goToThis"** on the first parent that matches v(weekNumber) which is v2 in this case.

Problem: It sets it on every parent and not only those which match "goToweek".

**I want it to only add "goToThis" on the first matching one.**

**Javascript**(RESULT = "2019, 2"):

```
function setAttributes()
{ 

    var goToweek = "<td>v" + result[1] + "</td>"
        elementos = document.body.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var is = 0, length = elementos.length; is < length; is++)
    {   

        for (var cc in goToweek)
        {
            if (elementos[is].innerHTML.indexOf(goToweek[cc]) !== -1)
            {   

                parentOfTds2 = (elementos[is]).parentNode;
                parentOfTds2.setAttribute("id", "goToThis");
            }
        };
    };
}
```

**Example HTML**:

```
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v22</td>
</tr>........
```

**After Code Execute:**:

```
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v4</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v5</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v6</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v7</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v8</td>
</tr>
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v22</td>
</tr>........
```

**I want:**

```
<tr id="goToThis">
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>v22</td>
</tr>........
```

Comment: You show the HTML result you want, but could you also show the HTML that actually results that you're trying to prevent? Also, `id` attributes have to be unique, so two different elements CANNOT have the same `id`.

Comment: `for (var cc in goToweek)` makes no sense given that `goToweek` is a *string*. What are you trying to do with that iteration? Don't you want to check `indexOf(goToweek)` with the *complete* string?

Comment: Also the thing you're trying to do does not make sense anyway, as "id" values should be *unique* on a given page.

Comment: You mean `result = [ 2019, 2 ]`?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey Updated, I know, worte that in the question. "I want it to only add "goToThis" on the first matching one."

Comment: @Bergi Im pretty new to JS, but when I checked online it told me to do cc in goToweek. Im not sure, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: @Pointy I know, read the description/ page again. Sorry for being unclear about it.

Comment: @Bargros Thank you, I'll try that, regarding id, I only want it to be put in the first matching object of (td which has a innerHTML of v(weekNumber).

Comment: @HerrSerker Output of a function called getWeekNumber, returns the value of 2019, 2.

Comment: @wiaK Where did you check online and who told you that? No, don't loop there, that's rubbish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution I whipped up.

```
function setAttributes() { 
   const elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   for (let is = 0; is < elementos.length; is++) { 
      const innerElements = elementos[is].children;
      if (innerElements[0].innerHTML === (""+result[0]) && innerElements[1].innerHTML === ("v"+result[1])) {   
          elementos[is].id = "goToThis";
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem I found from your example is that even if you compared the `innerHTML` of the element against `goToWeek` how would you be sure that the `td` for the year is the same as the year in you result array?

To avoid this instead of fetching all `td` I got all `tr` elements and checked that the year and week match and add the id to the corresponding `tr` parent and break out of the loop. This should attach **goToThis** to the first element matching the year and week.

Comment: If we have more than one td that has 2019 and 2, how do we only set the ID to the first matching?

Comment: Look at the `if` statement, if it matches the condition `innerElements[0].innerHTML === (""+result[0]) && innerElements[1].innerHTML === ("v"+result[1])` the if it'll set the **goToThis** as the `id` of the parent `tr` and break out of the loop, basically the function I gave you only looks for the first matching element and ignores anything else thereafter.

Comment: I've tried the code but it didn't work. Nothing happend at all. No errors as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I see no reason why this would not work, try printing results of `innerElements` and `elementos` with a `console.log(elementos);` before the loop and `console.log(innerElements);` before the `if` statement and report back the result.

Comment: "*Which are two completely different types, and it'd always return false.*" - No. Strings and single-character-strings are the same type in js, and in fact it will mostly return true because each of the elements contains a `v`.

Comment: @Bergi fair enough, upvoted, I can't believe i missed that.

Comment: I'm getting 
`HTMLCollection(697) [tr, tr, tr...]`
`HTMLCollection(26) [th, th, th...]`
`HTMLCollection(26) [td, td, td...]` (This one is looping a couple of times.)

Can you help me out here? @Bargros

Comment: Sorry my bad! I looked through the code again and found that `innnerElements` in the if statement reffered to the first and second value of elementos children when it should have been the second and third one. My example above was a little bit incorrect.

Thanks for the help @Bargros!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"), function(el, ind, arr) { // in this string we give all td elements and iterate they
    if (el.textContent === "v2" && !arr._mutching) { // search match element and watch flag
        el.parentNode.id = "goToThis"; // set for paren id
        arr._mutching = true; set flag for break all cycle
    }else{
        return;
    }
});
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v2</td>  <!-- will not mutch -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>v22</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This isnt a very helpful answer since you dont explain what what wrong or how you fixed it or why it went wrong in the first place. Our goal is to teach, not give the OP a solution.

Comment: i dont understand what "result[1]", where you give this variable

Comment: i added comments in my code for more explanations and describe my tech approach

Comment: I still think the answer could benefit from a short paragraph describing why the OP had the issue they had and how you solution differs from theirs but the comments are a step in the right direction!